# Overriding beans defined by @Component with beans defined in xml

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, annotations, overriding, managed-bean

I have a service MyService. In my controller, MyController I inject this service like this :

```
@Controller("myController")
@RequestMapping("/myController/dcb")
public class MyController{
...
@Autowired
private MyService myService;
...
}
```

Below is the service definition :

```
public interface MyService{
method1();
method2();
}
```

Below is the service implementation which I normally use.

```
@Service
@Component("myService")
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService{
...
@Override
method1(){
//Implementation of method1()
}

@Override
method2(){
//Implementation of method2()
method3();
}

method3(){
//This method is blank here
}
...
}
```

Now based on a requirement, I need to use an extension of **MyServiceImpl** which shall provide implementation of method3() (which is empty in **MyServiceImpl**) in it. This class shall be present in a separate project (say project 2) than **MyServiceImpl** (say project 1) and has the dependencies already configured in **'pom.xml'.**

```
public class RegionalMyServiceImpl extends MyServiceImpl {
method3(){
//Implementation of method3() goes here
}
...
}
```

Whenever **project 2** shall be started up, the **RegionalMyServiceImpl** object should be passed to the constructor '**MyController**'. This class shall have the implementation of method 3 already defined and extends all methods of MyServiceImpl too.

In order to do this I configured the bean name by '**myService**' with the class **RegionalMyServiceImpl**. As per my understanding, the bean definition in xml should override the bean constructed through the annotation **@Component** and whenever I start up project 2, the bean for **myService** will actually be of **RegionalMyServiceImpl** and not **MyServiceImpl**.

```
<bean id="myService" class="com.demo.RegionalMyServiceImpl"></bean>
```

Should this work? Is there any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this in controller:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("RegionalMyServiceImpl")
private MyService myService;
```

and edit bean definition:

```
<bean name="RegionalMyServiceImpl" class="com.demo.RegionalMyServiceImpl"></bean>
```

Comment: If this approach does work (I have not yet tested), then I would have to change my service injections to RegionalMyServiceImpl everywhere in my projects. There is a large number of controllers present.

Comment: For me, changing service injections everywhere is not problem. It's simple find and replace(How many files you will change ? 10 files, 100 files, ... ?) The problem here is how my solution improve your code quality. Besides, if I were you, I would tested my solution whether it works or not before I worry about how big effort you spend to fix. Even my solution doesn't fit for you but you have 1 more option at least.